# How to create a one to many and one many to many relationship between the same two tables in entity framework code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Hy I am struggling a bit mapping the following model:

```
[Table("ColumnRules")]
public class ColumnRuleEntity
{
    [Required]
    public virtual ColumnEntity ParentColumn { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ColumnEntity> DependentColumns { get; set; }
}
```

I added the following code to the On Model creating override:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ColumnRuleEntity>().HasMany(r => r.DependentColumns)
.WithMany().Map(mc => mc.ToTable("ColumnRuleDependentColumns")
.MapLeftKey("ColumnRuleId").MapRightKey("ColumnId"));
```

I am trying to create a OneToMany relationship using the ParentColumn property and a ManyToMany relationship using the DependentColumns property.

The problem I stumbled into is that this code alone would generate multiple cascade delete paths for data in the resulting link table. (deleting a Column would delete ColumnRules which would delete entries in the link table but at the same time by deleting a Column that should trigger the deletion of the same entries in the link table).

One solution i thought about was to create another entity which would represent an entry in the link table and cascade delete it only when deleting a ColumnRule entity and not when deleting a Column entity; but this is kind of cumbersome I think. Is there any other way this could be done?

Comment: And you don't want to disable cascading delete on the one-to-many relationship, right? That would be the solution which comes in mind as the first option...